# Changing the CSS on FireFox to look like Chrome Browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, admin

Please see the two photos in the link below.. The photo number 1 drop down arrow is how it should look and photo number 2 is how it looks on the Firefox browser. What CSS would I use to get the photo 2 drop down arrow to look like photo 1 on FireFox browser? Thanks for any help!

Here are the photoss - https://prnt.sc/pfcd3i

Comment: Try this  `-moz-appearance: none;` in your css.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have one option for all browser. what is it, background image method.
Find the following code

```
select{ 
    background : url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25623.svg) no-repeat;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-size: 11px;
    background-position: right 3px;
}
```

Just try this. Depends on your style you can adjust your style by moving this background position. Hope it will work...